# Is there a better way to measure CPU performance without impacting the performance?

Tags: c#, windows, performance, cpu, taskmanager

I need to find a way to measure RAM % usage and CPU % usage (as displayed in Task Manager, despite its inaccuracies) into an existing system. The method I decided on so far has been to use CMD and Powershell commands from within C# to get this information.

Below are the commands, saved into a ps1 file I use to collect all the variables I need:

```
$mem = cmd.exe /c 'wmic ComputerSystem get TotalPhysicalMemory && wmic OS get FreePhysicalMemory';
$loadpc = cmd.exe /c 'wmic cpu get loadpercentage';
$maxclock = cmd.exe /c 'wmic cpu get maxclockspeed';
$cpuperf = (Get-Counter -Counter '\Processor Information(_Total)\% Processor Performance').CounterSamples.CookedValue;
$mem,$loadpc,$maxclock,$cpuperf
```

This returns the total memory installed, total free memory available, the load percentage on the CPU, the base clock speed and the CPU performance. I use these numbers to calculate the RAM and CPU usages.

The .ps1 file is saved on a UNC path and I execute it on remote PCs using the below code:

```
private static List<double> GetResourceUsages(string hostname)
{
        string output = (LaunchProcess("powershell.exe", "-command Invoke-Command -ComputerName " + hostname + " -FilePath '<path>\\GetResources.ps1'"));
        output = RemoveSubstrings(new List<string>() { "TotalPhysicalMemory", "FreePhysicalMemory", "LoadPercentage", "-", "MaxClockSpeed", " " }, output);
        List<string> list = output.Split("\r\n").ToList();
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            if (list[i].Length == 0)
            {
                list.RemoveAt(i);
                i--;
            }
        }
        long.TryParse(list[0], out long MaxRAM);
        long.TryParse(list[1], out long AvailableRAM);
        double RAMUsage = (double)100 - ((double)AvailableRAM / (((double)MaxRAM) / 1024) * (double)100);
        Double.TryParse(list[2], out double loadPC);
        Double.TryParse(list[3], out double baseClock);
        Double.TryParse(list[4], out double perfPC);
        double CurrentCPUClock = (perfPC / 100) * baseClock;
        double CPUUtilization = loadPC / ((baseClock / CurrentCPUClock) * 100) * 100;
        return new List<double>() { RAMUsage, CPUUtilization };
}
```

This seems to work well. It allows me to calculate the RAM usage perfectly accurately, and the CPU usage matches Task Manager, [however inaccurate it is](https://linustechtips.com/topic/1225894-why-you-shouldnt-rely-on-task-manager-for-cpu-utilization/).

Now, the problem is, as the ps1 script is executed remotely, the remote PC's CPU usage will spike:
[Task Manager reading of CPU](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBaon.png)

The reason I am not using `PerformanceCounter` is because in order to calculate the CPU % usage as displayed in Task Manager, based on what I've learned, I need to do quite a bit of fuckery with the numbers, some of that involves getting the Processor Performance. I was not able to find a way to get this number using PerformanceCounter.

In any case, this method currently has too much of an impact on performance to be viable. Is there any other way to measure CPU performance *as displayed in task manager* or am I limited to WMI?

Comment: security wise you should be very careful with that `.ps` file location/permissions, otherwise you could get your network infected. Imagine someone changing the `.ps` file into a evil one... That could be fun

Comment: Cleptus, absolutely valid! The ps file is saved in a folder only a certain account has access to, and the application can only be used bu this account - no other account on the domain or off has access to it. Thank you for pointing that out, I should have included that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**`PerformanceCounter`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.performancecounter?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) to query the information you require (although it can be a bit tricky sometimes to use it).
I think this is cleaner than launching a power-shell script etc.
The code running this resource sampling can run in a separate exe, and communicate with your main one over tcp/ip sockets.

You mentioned that you didn't use the `PerformanceCounter` because *"I need to do quite a bit of fuckery with the numbers"*.
The chalange with `PerformanceCounter` is to find the name of the proper category and counter (and sometimes also the instance name).

The following code demonstrates sampling the CPU utilization (%) and available RAM (in MB).  There are many more counters. If you launch the Windows application **"Performance Monitor"** you'll be able to easilty see the available counters (there are a lot).

**I used the following:**
**CPU:** category: *"Processor Information"*, counter: *"% Processor Utility"*, instance: _"*Total"*.
**RAM:** category: *"Memory"*, counter: *"Available MBytes"*.

On my system it reports values that match the Task Manager.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        var cpuCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Processor Information", "% Processor Utility", "_Total");
        var ramCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Available MBytes");

        while (true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            double cpuSample = cpuCounter.NextValue();
            double ramSample = ramCounter.NextValue();
            Console.WriteLine("CPU utilization (%):" + cpuSample + ",  Available RAM (MB): " + ramSample);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works very well! Thank you for that! Previously when I tried to use PerformanceCounters, I always got the "The network path was not found" error, which I couldn't resolve after hours of Google-ing, and after trying your code, I got the same error, but 1 Google search now found the resolution to that...

The Remote Registry service must be enabled and running.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Right off the bat, a large amount of processing and I/O power will be spent spawning and killing command interpreters and loading, running and unloading `wmic` over and over again.

You can trivially do all your logic in one process, either through one PS script (which supports WMI queries out of the box, and you seem to be using anyway) or by writing your own executable that does the querying and gathering of data.

Also, there are much better ways of sending and receiving data across computers than spawning remote processes and parsing their text outputs, like pipes or sockets. A UDP socket is many orders of magnitude more efficient than what you have set up there.